# What is the accurate English translation of Judges 8:18 (Codex Alexandrinus)?

Tags: greek, septuagint, judges, manuscript

> καὶ εἶπεν πρὸς Ζεβεε καὶ Σαλμανα ποῦ οἱ ἄνδρες οὓς ἀπεκτείνατε ἐν
>   Θαβωρ καὶ εἶπαν ὡσεὶ σύ ὅμοιος σοί ὅμοιος αὐτῶν ὡς εἶδος μορφὴ υἱῶν
>   βασιλέων  **Judges 8:18 A**

### What is the English translation that is as accurate as possible and as literal as possible of Judges 8:18 (Codex Alexandrinus) ?

I can't see an English translation of it. NRSV, RSV and DRA that use the LXX use a different MSS.

Comment: NRSV and RSV are both based on the MT, not LXX.  DRA is a translation from the Latin derived from Jerome's translation of a Hebrew text of his time.  Two versions that do use the LXX are Brenton's 1851 translation and the SAAS LXX in the Orthodox Study Bible.  Both of these, however, are based on the Vaticanus as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textual situation of LXX Judges is somewhat unusual (although not wholly unique). As Philip E. Satterthwaite explains it in his introduction to the [NETS edition](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets) of [Judges](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/edition/07-judges-nets.pdf),

> [In the absence of a modern critical text, t]he NETS translation of Judges ... is based on A. Rahlfs, 
>   *Septuaginta. Id
>   est Vetus  Testamentum  graece  iuxta  LXX  interpretes*,  2  vols.
>   (Stuttgart:  Württembergische  Bibelanstalt,
>   1935).
>
> In  Judges  Rahlfs  based  his  edition  on  the  readings  of  about  twenty  manuscripts.  He  identified  two
>   main  textual  traditions,  which  he  believed  were  so  diverse  that  they  amounted  to  separate  recensions
>   (editions) of the book. He printed these as separate texts, designated A and B. NETS Judges, accordingly,
>   offers a translation of both the A and the B texts.
>
> Rahlfs based his A text upon Codex Alexandrinus (A) and two groups of manuscripts representing the
>   recensions of the LXX associated, respectively, with Origen (c. 185–253 CE) and Lucian (c. 250–312 CE).
>   His B text was based upon Codex Vaticanus (B).

Satterthwaite offers much more comment on this textual situation in the remainder of that introduction.

For 8:18, the A and B texts are not all that different, and those differences are confined to the second half of the verse (I've placed in italics, below). These are Satterthwaite's translations:

> **A:** καὶ εἶπεν πρὸς Ζεβεε καὶ Σαλμανα ποῦ οἱ ἄνδρες οὓς ἀπεκτείνατε ἐν Θαβωρ καὶ εἶπαν *ὡσεὶ σύ ὅμοιος σοί ὅμοιος αὐτῶν ὡς εἶδος μορφὴ υἱῶν βασιλέων*
>   = And he said to Zebee and Salmana, “Where
>   are  the  men  whom  you  killed  at  Thabor?”  And
>   they said, “As you are: one like you was like them,
>   like  the  appearance,  the  form,  of  kings’  sons.”

But:

> **B:** καὶ εἶπεν πρὸς Ζεβεε καὶ Σελμανα ποῦ οἱ ἄνδρες οὓς ἀπεκτείνατε ἐν Θαβωρ καὶ εἶπαν *ὡς σύ ὣς αὐτοὶ εἰς ὁμοίωμα υἱοῦ βασιλέως*
>   = And he said to Zebee and Selmana, “Where
>   are  the  men  whom  you  killed  at  Thabor?”  And
>   they said, “As you are, so were they, for a likeness
>   of  a  king’s  son.”

---

For the banter, this is what the "A" and "B" texts look like set out in Rahlfs' *Septuaginta*; note 'A' and 'B' designations in inside margin:

[image: Rahlfs Judges]